# Can I reference a Path Variable in Intellij IDEA Run Configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 14, I've defined a Path Variable FOO (in Preferences). The IDEA docs are ambiguous about where these variables can be used... Can I reference FOO in a (Tomcat) Run Configuration > VM Options ie:

```
-DmyProp=$FOO$
```

Also is it $FOO$ or $FOO?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can reference them in a Tomcat run configuration, but it's certainly `$FOO`, not `$FOO$`

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is 3 years old, but is still comes up in Google when one searches for solution to this problem, so I thought I should post the answer anyway.

It is possible to use Path Variables in Run Configurations (tested on IntelliJ 2018.1, should work the same on older versions) and here's how:

1. Use the variable in Your Run Configuration using syntax: `-DmyProp=$FOO$`
2. Restart IntelliJ or close and reopen the project.
3. When you reopen Your Run Configuration you should see: `-DmyProp='the value of FOO'`.

If you open the project files in a text editor, you will still see `-DmyProp=$FOO$`, however when the project is loaded IntelliJ automatically replaces it with the current value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. This Variable are interpreted with a command processor like shell or windows batch.
On Unix it is $FOO on Win %FOO%.

You can create different Run Configurations with the $FOO replacements and save it.

Examples:
Config1: -DmyProp=blah1
Config2: -DmyProp=blah2
etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about environment variables, not (idea-proprietary) Path Variables

Comment: Yes I do, because path variables can't be used in run configurations

Comment: As it described in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/path-variables.html
is a variable whose value is an absolute path to a directory or file

Comment: you can use path variables in run configurations. Just need to restart the editor and it will work. it will also replace all hardcoded paths in your runconfigurations with the path variable if they match